# Transforming data from multiple columns to rows and keeping "labels"

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, split, flatten, google-query-language

I am trying to create a Google Sheet where some of the data is inputet on a column basis.
Like this

[image]

This input is done in a Input sheet. And then I want to transform the data into this form in the Output sheet.

[image]

I have no idea how I could do this in a simple way. I did think about some solution using the Transpose function, but I can't realy wrap my head around how to solve this.

Here is a link to the sheet if anyone can help me out:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W244e2IOyORYyMPg6VnRiYDgX2ux7VZn4N27mEUSOII/edit#gid=1942499075

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF('Input sheet'!C4:L="",,
 'Input sheet'!A4:A&"×"&'Input sheet'!B4:B&"×"&'Input sheet'!C3:L3&"×"&'Input sheet'!C4:L)), "×"), 
 "where Col2 is not null"))
```

[image]

Comment: It only works if iterative calculations is On, and then it recalculates on every click it seems

Comment: @Siesta nah, you are using it wrong way... use it in other sheet not in range A4:L of current (input) range. if you want it to use it in input sheet either restrict ranges in formula or use it from column M onwards

Comment: Oh, your right. When added in the other sheet it worked!

Comment: If @player0's answer was successful, you could mark it as accepted.